# Using bloc and dropdown menu in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc, rxdart

Hi I am new to flutter and have been going through flutter's udacity course building their unit converter app to try to learn about the framework. I was attempting to architecture the app using bloc but have ran into an issue with my dropdown menu. Every time when I change the item in the dropdown it resets back to the default value when focusing on the text input field. It looks like the widget tree i rebuilt when focusing on a textfield. The default units are the reset because in my bloc constructor I have a method to set default units. I am at a loss for where I would move my default units method so that it does not conflict. What should I do in my bloc to set default units only when a distinct category is set, and when it is first being built.

I tried using _currentCatController.stream.distinct method to only update the stream when distinct data is passed but that did not seem to work either. I tried to wrap the default units method in various conditional statements that did not give me the result I wanted.

you can find all the source here https://github.com/Renzo-Olivares/Units_Flutter

```
class _ConverterScreenState extends State<ConverterScreen> {
  ///function that creates dropdown widget
  Widget _buildDropdown(
      bool selectionType, ValueChanged<dynamic> changeFunction) {
    print("build dropdown");
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, style: BorderStyle.solid),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: ButtonTheme(
              alignedDropdown: true,
              child: StreamBuilder<Unit>(
                  stream: _conversionBloc.inputUnit,
                  initialData: widget._category.units[0],
                  builder: (context, snapshotIn) {
                    return StreamBuilder<Unit>(
                        stream: _conversionBloc.outputUnit,
                        initialData: widget._category.units[1],
                        builder: (context, snapshotOut) {
                          return StreamBuilder<Category>(
                              stream: _conversionBloc.currentCategory,
                              initialData: widget._category,
                              builder: (context, snapshotDropdown) {
                                return DropdownButton(
                                  items: snapshotDropdown.data.units
                                      .map(_buildDropdownItem)
                                      .toList(),
                                  value: selectionType
                                      ? snapshotIn.data.name
                                      : snapshotOut.data.name,
                                  onChanged: changeFunction,
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  hint: Text("Select Units",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )),
                                );
                              });
                        });
                  })),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ConversionBloc {
  //input
  final _currentCatController = StreamController<Category>();
  Sink<Category> get currentCat => _currentCatController.sink;

  final _currentCatSubject = BehaviorSubject<Category>();
  Stream<Category> get currentCategory => _currentCatSubject.stream;

  ConversionBloc() {
    print("conversion bloc");
    //category
    _currentCatController.stream.listen((category) {
      print("setting category ${category.name}");
      _category = category;
      _currentCatSubject.sink.add(_category);

      //units default
      setDefaultUnits(_category);
    });
  }

  void setDefaultUnits(Category category) {
    print("setting default units for ${category.name}");
    _inputUnits = category.units[0];
    _outputUnits = category.units[1];
    _inputUnitSubject.sink.add(_inputUnits);
    _outputUnitSubject.add(_outputUnits);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the DropdownButton `value` wasn't updated on `onChanged`. What you can do here is handle the value passed from onChanged and update the DropdownButton value. Also, focusing on a Widget displayed on screen shouldn't rebuild `Widget build()`.